# Cant Install php 7.2 extensions on ubuntu 16

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt

I wanted to install two extensions on my ubuntu 16.04 and after doing all necessary, its not happend.

i did this steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php7.2-zstd (or php7.2-dev)
```

it returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-zstd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-zstd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-zstd'
```

and my php -v:

```
PHP 7.2.34-28+0~20211119.67+debian9~1.gbpf24e81 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2021 06:42:03) ( 
NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.34-28+0~20211119.67+debian9~1.gbpf24e81, Copyright (c) 1999- 
2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is pretty outdated, and `ppa:ondrej/php` does not support outdated systems

Comment: See https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1567 for details

Comment: Try `pecl install zstd`

Comment: @NicoHaase then what i have to do?

Comment: @shingo cant install it by pecl cause pecl requires php-dev , and cant install it too.

Comment: Either upgrade your server, or use any other way to install the packages (like compiling them by hand or use a payed service, as documented by Ondrej in the linked post)

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/